# SQLite retrive number with 2 decimal places

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `InvoiceHeader` Table.

```
 CREATE TABLE WMInvoiceHeader (
BusinessUnit        char(4) NOT NULL ,
RetailerCode        char(10) ,
GrossValue      real,
InvoiceValue        real,
TotalLineDiscount   real,
TotalHeaderDiscount real,
VATValue        real,
UpdatedOn       datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (BusinessUnit ASC,).
```

When I save data to database, it save with two decimal place

Example:

```
  BusinessUnit  RetailerCode     GrossValue    InvoiceValue
   Test         Test1            152.65        152.65
```

But When retrive the value from db, it retrun `GrossValue` with `152.7` . Its rounded.

Query is :

```
    String query = "SELECT BusinessUnit,GrossValue,InvoiceValue,TotalLineDiscount,"
                FROM WMInvoiceHeader 
                WHERE (CancelFlag IS NULL OR CancelFlag ='0') AND UploadFlag='1'";
          ArrayList<?> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
          for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<?> arrayList = (ArrayList<?>) stringList.get(i);
                ArrayList<?> list = arrayList;
                grossValue = Double.parseDouble((String)list.get(7));
        System.out.println(grossValue ); //give 152.7
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: save as String value. and get it then convert into decimal or float..

Comment: When I print `(String)list.get(7)` this value, it return rounded value.

Comment: so what.?? save in string variable..

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to display 2 decimal places, you have to store it in the database with at least 3  and the variable that handles it in the application also needs 3 decimal places.